# How to get 'me/photos' by Facebook Query Language (FQL)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I just wanted to get photos of me taken in specified year, say 2009.

By using Facebook Graph API, my photos can be get by querying `/me/photos`
(c.f. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

But this way, we cannot filter pictures. By using FQL, we can filter photos. However, to get `/me/photos` by FQL seems complicated.

Does anyone know exact query to get `/me/photos/` by FQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of my research, the query

`SELECT src_big, caption, created, like_info FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me())`

best fits for `/me/photos`.

By using this, you can limit photo results by `created` time or `like_info.like_count` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `photo` table contains an `owner` index which you can use to extract all photo's belonging to a certain user. The `me()` function simply uses the user_id of the current user.

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE owner = me()
```

This query will return object_ids for each photo that belongs to the user. You can add more parameters to extract more useful data:

```
SELECT object_id, created, src_big FROM photo WHERE owner = me()
```

This will give you along with the object_id, the creation date and a link to the large version of the image itself.

You'll see a response similar to this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object_id": "123", 
      "created": 1385923483, 
      "src_big": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-...jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "object_id": "456", 
      "created": 1384765782, 
      "src_big": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-...jpg"                            
    }, 
    {
      "object_id": "789", 
      "created": 1384144732, 
      "src_big": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-...jpg"                            
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is not what `/me/photos` returns. Please check at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Yes - because when using `me/photos` you get all of the photos that you are tagged in - not necessarily the photos that belong to you. With the FQL call, we are selecting only photos that are *owned* by the user. You'll need to be a little more specific about what types of photos you want. Photo's the user is tagged in or photos owned by the user.

Comment: Ok, so my questions is, what `/me/photos` do if you write by FQL?

Comment: You're not looking at the problem correctly. You need to decide exactly what type of information you want. Once you know, you can use either the Graph API or FQL to get it. But you need to decide first what you need.

Comment: My task is to replace graph api, which is used currently on production, to fql to filter photos by created or like count etc. So I need to know what `/me/photos/` exactly do. Do you get it? :)

Comment: As referenced by the [user endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) which is what you get when you use `/me`, the photos endpoint contains `"Photos the user (or friend) is tagged in."`.

Comment: You won't be able to get exactly the same thing with FQL because you need to be specific about who's photo's you want to retrieve.